# What is the context of the Javascript running in web components?

Tags: javascript, web-component

I was wondering if I have 3 functions that are defined in the global space in my Web component code, will this pollute the global space of the hosting app?

I know the Web Component CSS is isolated with **Shadow Boundary** but is the Javascript also isolated this way?